# WPF MVVM: Switch from one User Control to Another on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been slowly playing around with MVVM and the concept makes since. I have an application window and 2 user controls with viewModels attached to each. I want to click on a button within the first user control and get taken to the second user control.

I've looked at a few tutorials such as:
[Example 1](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)[Example 2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30898.simple-navigation-technique-in-wpf-using-mvvm.aspx)

Both those change screens from within the main window view model but I'd like to do it within the user control itself. Is it possible to either pass a command to change windows back to the main application view model, or have the user control model change the view on button click.

Edit: I figure I need to pass it as a command but I'm not sure how to pass which view I want along with it.

Comment: `DataTemplates` serves this purpose. Add each of your UserControls as DataTemplates to your window. In your ViewModel, create a public property that controls the type of View you want to see. In your window, create a DataTrigger that switches the DataTemplate based on the value of this property.

Comment: Also understand that commands generally work at ViewModel level and have nothing to do with (or have any knowledge of) the View layer. Your commands will simply manipulate the value of the public property (as I described above) and the DataTriggers in your view will respond accordingly to load proper DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM, commands generally work at ViewModel level and have nothing to do with (or have any knowledge of) the View layer. To achieve what you have described, create a public property that controls the type of View you want to see. For example (using MVVM Light):

```
class YourViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public string ActiveView
  {
    get { return _ApplicationMessage; }

    //Note that this setter performs notification
    set { Set(ref _ApplicationMessage, value); }
  }

  private RelayCommand<string> _SetViewCommand = null;

  public RelayCommand<string> SetViewCommand
  {
    get
    {
      if (_SetViewCommand == null)
      {
        _SetViewCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((v) =>
        {
          ActiveView = v;
        }
      }

      return _SetViewCommand;
    }
  }
}
```

As you see, your commands will simply manipulate the value of the public property to the appropriate value. Now your View can build on top of this property and use `DataTrigger`s to load proper Content:

```
<Button Content="Normal" Command="{Binding SetViewCommand}" CommandParameter="Normal" />
<Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding SetViewCommand}" CommandParameter="Edit" />

<ContentControl>
  <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveView}" Value="Normal">
          <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
              <UserControl1 />
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveView}" Value="Edit">
          <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
              <UserControl2 />
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

### Edit

Answering your comment:

*view doesn't really interact with the viewModel*: That's incorrect. View always interacts with the VM, it is the VM that doesn't know anything about the view. About your confusion, understand that **you don't need to create one VM per user control. A VM is created against a View, not a control.** So you'll probably have a single ViewModel named MainVM, exposing all the public properties that your view will bind to. Each User Control can then use only the properties that it is interested in. A trigger can then switch the view from one User Control to another when a particular property of the underlying VM is changed. The new User Control will then show correct data since it will be bound to the VM properties that it wants to work with.

Just remember that the VM is not interested in (nor have a way of) knowing how view is using it. It just needs to maintain its state correctly. View can then respond to the state changes and update itself accordingly.

Comment: So I'll do some reading up on Data Triggers, but I think whats confusing me is what actually switches the view. Is User Control 1 passing data to The main window viewModel, or is the User Control 1 view model actually changing the view to User Control 2. I do understand that the view doesn't really interact with the viewModel, But both user controls are contained in a MainWindow so I figured the MainWindow viewModel should actually switch the windows.